# How to receive multiple packets using UDP at a single socket in a single array

Tags: c#

I need to receive multiple packets but I am getting only one packet and i want the values of the next should overwrite the values of the previous packet in the same array

For example the sample of my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using microLCC;

namespace A2LDFCSolver
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    int m;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    //byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1235);
    Socket newsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPEndPoint sen = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);
    microLCC.microLCC uLC = new microLCC.microLCC();
    EndPoint tmp;
    StateObject obj = new StateObject();
    int count = 0; 
    int cout = 0;

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newsocket.Bind(endpoint);
        tmp = (EndPoint)sen;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bw_Reset(object sender,   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Message Recieved" + count.ToString();
    }

    private void bw_doit(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    { 
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        while (true)
        {
            allDone.Reset();
            //newsocket.ReceiveFrom(data, 0, 40, SocketFlags.None, ref tmp);
            newsocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, 40, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    protected void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        //Socket newsocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        //newsocket.EndReceive(ar);
        count = count + 1;
        for (m = 0; m <= 17; m = m + 1)
        {
            if (m <= 7)
            {
                uLC.setDAC_raw(m, data[m]);
            }
            if (m >= 8 && m <= 14)
            {
                if (data[m] == 1)
                {
                    uLC.setRelay((m - 7), true);
                }
                if (data[m] == 0)
                {
                    uLC.setRelay((m - 7), false);
                }
            }
            if (m == 15)
            {
                uLC.setEPM_CaS(data[m]);
            }
            if (m == 16)
            {
                uLC.setEPM_CrS(data[m]);
            }
        }
        send(newsocket);
    }

    private void send(Socket newsocket)
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = (Byte)uLC.getADC(i);

        }
        newsocket.BeginSendTo(buffer, 0, 7, 0, sen,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
    }

    protected void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            int s = newsocket.EndSendTo(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }
}


public class StateObject
{
  public Socket workSocket = null;
  public const int BufferSize = 1024;
  public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Here I am receiving the values only one time in my data array but if I need to receive more than one packets in the single array then how can I do that .

Please help me

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

```
IPEndPoint sen = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);    
EndPoint tmp = (EndPoint)sen;    
newsocket.Bind(endpoint);
int count=0;
while(newsocket.Available>0 && count<data.Length)
{
   count+= newsocket.ReceiveFrom(data,count, 40, SocketFlags.None, ref tmp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help this is working but actually according to my requirements i need the values of 2nd packet should come in the starting of the array..for example I need to get only 17 values which can be stored from the 1st place of an array till the 17th place of an array and if i get another packet it should overwrite the previous values of an array and and should start from the first place of an array....

Comment: @user1465977:- newsocket.ReceiveFrom(data,0, 40,..) and declare an arraylist and keep adding to it the incoming packets.

Comment: @ Anon ymous:- thanks again can you please tell me by writing a code how can i do that..

Comment: Hello to all,my problem i want to receive multiple packets from the client side but i am getting only one packet here is the example of my code..how can i do that if someone have any information about it please help me in that..here is the example of my code..